# Apache VirtualHost won't work (Wamp/Win7)

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost, wampserver, virtual-hosts

I own two domains which I want to point to my local server here at home:

1. www.first.com
2. www.second.com

They both point to my own server here at home (Yes I've already managed the A-record config at my webhotel where I registered the domains).

I've done the following:

1. In httpd.conf, I've uncommented the line `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
2. In httpd-vhosts.conf I have the following code:

   ```
   NameVirtualHost *:80
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName first.com
       ServerAlias www.first.com
       DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/public/first"
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName second.com
       ServerAlias www.second.com
       DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/public/second"
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. In the httpd.conf file, I've set document-root to `C:\wamp\www\public`, and this is the step I'm most uncertain of. What should the document root be in the httpd.conf file when the httpd-vhosts.conf file declares multiple document roots? I've tried to set the document root of httpd.conf to both `C:/wamp/www/public` and only `C:/wamp/www/`

What am I missing here? The pages won't load at all.

Comment: Did you ever check your `error.log` file? If yes, what kind of error you see? Please post some of them.

Answer (score 0):

DocumentRoot for "main" server haven't sense as soon as you define Virthosts - known virthosts will be served from their definition, unknown - by first virthost in list

Create separate log-files per virthost and yes, check logs after access attept

> The pages won't load at all

It's bad error-description. Which error-code you get? Do you have DirectoryIndex and index-file in virthost root? What about Allow/Disallow directives for Directory locations?